# postgres performs bad on index_only scan (1.000.000+ loops)

Tags: postgresql

i have 2 postgres table set up like this:

`record: id (bigserial) | client varchar(10) | record_number varchar(10) | data varchar(255)`

`person: id (bigserial) | record_id (bigint, fk) | number varchar(10)`

`number`and `record_number` and `client` are business keys of external systems.

My indexes are defined like this (omitting the primary key indexes):

```
unique constraint on record (client, record_number) --> record_client_record_number_key
unique constraint on person (record_number, number) --> person_record_id_number_key
create index record_client_record_number_idx on record (client, record_number);
create index person_record_id_number_idx on person (record_id, number);
create index person_number_idx on person (number);
```

Both tables see very little writing activity (say 100-150 new rows per day).

I just did `vacuum` and `analyze` both tables.

`record` currently sits at 11.500.000 rows.
`person` currently sits at 70.000.000 rows.

the query in question is this (give me the first 10 records of client '1' for person '123', ordered by record_number):

```
select record_number, data 
from record 
inner join person on person.record_id = record.id
where record.client = '1' and person.number = '123'
order by record.record_number
limit 10;
```

This query is slow (20 seconds) when querying for a person that has 100.000 or more records assigned. This affects less than 1% of the records, the mean number of records per person is about 5.

The execution plan tells me, the slowest part (89% of the time spent) is an index_only scan on `person_record_id_number_idx`, performing roughly 1.000.000 (for some records almost 2.000.000) loops, taking 0,0xx milliseconds, which adds up to about 20+ seconds.

My guess is that these few cases slip through the query planner and the query is optimised for the mean case? How would i go about handling this?

this is the execution plan once easy to look at, once in json as gotten from `explain (ANALYZE, COSTS, VERBOSE, BUFFERS, FORMAT JSON)`:

(the total time is actually more like 20 seconds, I do not know why the "total" says 9 seconds)

http://tatiyants.com/pev/#/plans/plan_1566906780689

@EDIT1:

I reran the query for the TEXT format, the issue is the same, the number are different than in the graphical representation

```
"Limit  (cost=1001.15..2387.23 rows=10 width=11) (actual time=2960.719..3887.492 rows=10 loops=1)"
"  Output: record.record_number"
"  Buffers: shared hit=3277282 read=1440334"
"  ->  Gather Merge  (cost=1001.15..14699396.01 rows=106043 width=11) (actual time=2960.718..3887.486 rows=10 loops=1)"
"        Output: record.record_number"
"        Workers Planned: 2"
"        Workers Launched: 2"
"        Buffers: shared hit=3277282 read=1440334"
"        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1.13..14686156.00 rows=44185 width=11) (actual time=2380.483..3590.828 rows=5 loops=3)"
"              Output: record.record_number"
"              Buffers: shared hit=3277282 read=1440334"
"              Worker 0: actual time=2956.001..3877.582 rows=4 loops=1"
"                Buffers: shared hit=1184337 read=520442"
"              Worker 1: actual time=2082.373..3876.877 rows=6 loops=1"
"                Buffers: shared hit=1233062 read=541638"
"              ->  Parallel Index Scan using record_client_record_number_key on public.record  (cost=0.56..5863685.61 rows=2993449 width=19) (actual time=0.249..1265.516 rows=313959 loops=3)"
"                    Output: record.id, record.client, record.record_number"
"                    Index Cond: ((record.client)::text = ‘1'::text)"
"                    Buffers: shared hit=289054 read=656394"
"                    Worker 0: actual time=0.074..1358.515 rows=340356 loops=1"
"                      Buffers: shared hit=104448 read=237194"
"                    Worker 1: actual time=0.040..1376.870 rows=354326 loops=1"
"                      Buffers: shared hit=108824 read=246845"
"              ->  Index Only Scan using person_record_id_number_key on public.person  (cost=0.57..2.94 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.007..0.007 rows=0 loops=941877)"
"                    Output: person.record_id, person.number"
"                    Index Cond: ((person.record_id = record.id) AND (person.number = ‘123'::text))"
"                    Heap Fetches: 0"
"                    Buffers: shared hit=2988228 read=783940"
"                    Worker 0: actual time=0.007..0.007 rows=0 loops=340356"
"                      Buffers: shared hit=1079889 read=283248"
"                    Worker 1: actual time=0.007..0.007 rows=0 loops=354326"
"                      Buffers: shared hit=1124238 read=294793"
"Planning time: 0.740 ms"
"Execution time: 3887.535 ms"
```

EDIT2:

here is a plan for another person with 200k records. this one took 77 seconds.

```
"Limit  (cost=1001.15..2387.23 rows=10 width=11) (actual time=77143.580..77231.907 rows=10 loops=1)"
"  Output: record.record_number"
"  Buffers: shared hit=10195921 read=4836555 written=31"
"  ->  Gather Merge  (cost=1001.15..14699396.01 rows=106043 width=11) (actual time=77143.578..77231.902 rows=10 loops=1)"
"        Output: record.record_number"
"        Workers Planned: 2"
"        Workers Launched: 2"
"        Buffers: shared hit=10195921 read=4836555 written=31"
"        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1.13..14686156.00 rows=44185 width=11) (actual time=77131.185..77181.249 rows=5 loops=3)"
"              Output: record.record_number"
"              Buffers: shared hit=10195921 read=4836555 written=31"
"              Worker 0: actual time=77139.897..77220.886 rows=3 loops=1"
"                Buffers: shared hit=3333309 read=1590898 written=13"
"              Worker 1: actual time=77115.080..77177.258 rows=10 loops=1"
"                Buffers: shared hit=3465191 read=1635783 written=10"
"              ->  Parallel Index Scan using record_client_record_number_key on public.record  (cost=0.56..5863685.61 rows=2993449 width=19) (actual time=0.024..21071.602 rows=1000427 loops=3)"
"                    Output: record.id, record.client, record.record_number"
"                    Index Cond: ((record.client)::text = ‘1'::text)"
"                    Buffers: shared hit=776210 read=2236401 written=15"
"                    Worker 0: actual time=0.022..21147.630 rows=983134 loops=1"
"                      Buffers: shared hit=250562 read=736286 written=4"
"                    Worker 1: actual time=0.026..20896.810 rows=1018410 loops=1"
"                      Buffers: shared hit=266537 read=755714 written=7"
"              ->  Index Only Scan using person_record_id_number_key on public.person  (cost=0.57..2.94 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.056..0.056 rows=0 loops=3001282)"
"                    Output: person.record_id, person.number"
"                    Index Cond: ((person.record_id = record.id) AND (person.number = ‘123'::text))"
"                    Heap Fetches: 0"
"                    Buffers: shared hit=9419711 read=2600154 written=16"
"                    Worker 0: actual time=0.057..0.057 rows=0 loops=983134"
"                      Buffers: shared hit=3082747 read=854612 written=9"
"                    Worker 1: actual time=0.055..0.055 rows=0 loops=1018410"
"                      Buffers: shared hit=3198654 read=880069 written=3"
"Planning time: 0.335 ms"
"Execution time: 77231.941 ms"
```

EDIT3:

with appending an empty string to the sort column:

```
"Gather Merge  (cost=1430776.48..1630073.86 rows=1708144 width=43) (actual time=42134.662..47057.274 rows=3291303 loops=1)"
"  Output: record.record_number, (((record.record_number)::text || ''::text))"
"  Workers Planned: 2"
"  Workers Launched: 2"
"  Buffers: shared hit=291072 read=576381 dirtied=1, temp read=147512 written=146831"
"  ->  Sort  (cost=1429776.46..1431911.64 rows=854072 width=43) (actual time=42018.742..43379.011 rows=1097101 loops=3)"
"        Output: record.record_number, (((record.record_number)::text || ''::text))"
"        Sort Key: (((record.record_number)::text || ''::text))"
"        Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 35152kB"
"        Buffers: shared hit=291072 read=576381 dirtied=1, temp read=147512 written=146831"
"        Worker 0: actual time=41850.406..43248.277 rows=1066945 loops=1"
"          Buffers: shared hit=119447 read=162822 dirtied=1, temp read=48803 written=48575"
"        Worker 1: actual time=42114.443..43546.456 rows=1102416 loops=1"
"          Buffers: shared hit=89039 read=196529, temp read=49209 written=48982"
"        ->  Hash Join  (cost=497872.85..1319358.79 rows=854072 width=43) (actual time=10994.338..37788.898 rows=1097101 loops=3)"
"              Output: record.record_number, ((record.record_number)::text || ''::text)"
"              Inner Unique: true"
"              Hash Cond: (person.record_id = record.id)"
"              Buffers: shared hit=291058 read=576379 dirtied=1, temp read=127925 written=127163"
"              Worker 0: actual time=10985.804..37729.738 rows=1066945 loops=1"
"                Buffers: shared hit=119439 read=162822 dirtied=1, temp read=42542 written=42288"
"              Worker 1: actual time=10985.711..37838.847 rows=1102416 loops=1"
"                Buffers: shared hit=89033 read=196527, temp read=42661 written=42407"
"              ->  Parallel Bitmap Heap Scan on public.person  (cost=75049.65..838207.10 rows=1350596 width=8) (actual time=630.187..24513.048 rows=1097101 loops=3)"
"                    Output: person.record_id"
"                    Recheck Cond: ((person.number)::text = ‘123'::text)"
"                    Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 10675594"
"                    Heap Blocks: exact=15313 lossy=122773"
"                    Buffers: shared hit=1 read=420565 dirtied=1"
"                    Worker 0: actual time=623.043..24504.919 rows=1066945 loops=1"
"                      Buffers: shared read=133283 dirtied=1"
"                    Worker 1: actual time=622.762..24510.162 rows=1102416 loops=1"
"                      Buffers: shared read=136582"
"                    ->  Bitmap Index Scan on person_number_idx  (cost=0.00..74239.29 rows=3241430 width=0) (actual time=629.148..629.148 rows=3291303 loops=1)"
"                          Index Cond: ((person.number)::text = ‘123'::text)"
"                          Buffers: shared hit=1 read=12614"
"              ->  Hash  (cost=290923.72..290923.72 rows=7184278 width=19) (actual time=10353.024..10353.024 rows=7231896 loops=3)"
"                    Output: record.record_number, record.id"
"                    Buckets: 65536  Batches: 128  Memory Usage: 3600kB"
"                    Buffers: shared hit=290936 read=155800, temp written=115422"
"                    Worker 0: actual time=10351.368..10351.368 rows=7231896 loops=1"
"                      Buffers: shared hit=119375 read=29537, temp written=38474"
"                    Worker 1: actual time=10351.346..10351.346 rows=7231896 loops=1"
"                      Buffers: shared hit=88979 read=59933, temp written=38474"
"                    ->  Seq Scan on public.record  (cost=0.00..290923.72 rows=7184278 width=19) (actual time=0.191..7878.983 rows=7231896 loops=3)"
"                          Output: record.record_number, record.id"
"                          Filter: ((record.client)::text = ‘1'::text)"
"                          Rows Removed by Filter: 4128874"
"                          Buffers: shared hit=290936 read=155800"
"                          Worker 0: actual time=0.029..7545.023 rows=7231896 loops=1"
"                            Buffers: shared hit=119375 read=29537"
"                          Worker 1: actual time=0.023..8062.271 rows=7231896 loops=1"
"                            Buffers: shared hit=88979 read=59933"
"Planning time: 4.141 ms"
"Execution time: 47265.094 ms"
```

Comment: "*the total time is actually more like 20 seconds, I do not know why the "total" says 9 seconds*" where did you measure those 20 seconds? The time reported in the execution plan is the time it took to run the query **on the server**. If you see 20 seconds in your SQL client, then that includes the time to send the data from the server to your computer and most probably also the time it took your SQL client to display the data

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name the plan's times add up to 20 seconds in the json result - this is why the graphical tool tells me that the index_only scan took more than 100% of the total time - which makes no sense. The total in the text representation I added now is correct (~3 seconds) - subsequent queries are significantly faster (x10) for the same input, I'll have to wait 10 minutes for a result with ~30 seconds again

Comment: I found another person that causes the issue - i added the execution plan too, the index_only scan does 3 Million loops there

Answer (score 1):

Obviously the `record`s that match the condition all have high `record_number`, so PostgreSQL's strategy to join the data in `record_number` order until it has found 10 matches does not work out.

Tell PostgreSQL to choose a different strategy:

```
SELECT record_number, data 
FROM record 
   JOIN person ON person.record_id = record.id
WHERE record.client = '1' AND person.number = '123'
ORDER BY record.record_number || ''
LIMIT 10;
```

To make the query as fast as possible, do the following:

- Create the index

  ```
  CREATE INDEX ON record (client, record_number, id);
  ```

  With PostgreSQL v11, you could use:

  ```
  CREATE INDEX ON record (client) INCLUDE (record_number, id);
  ```
- `VACCUM` the table:

  ```
  VACUUM (ANALYZE) record;
  ```
- Increase `work_mem` until the `lossy` in the *bitmap heap scan* goes away and the *sort method* is no longer an external disk sort.

It will still not be blazingly fast, but that's as good as it gets.

Comment: Thanks - i already vacuumed and analyzed all tables multiple times today.
I don't know if appending an empt string is an option really - the query is created by hibernate unfortunately - is there a way to do this another way?

Comment: Follow my instructions one by one and see. The `VACUUM` is to build the visibility map for the table.

Comment: I did that - these steps in itself did not improve the query (it uses the new index though) - but I observed something curious: one person has 3.000.000 records assigned - the index only scan for that person takes 1 loop & 30ms total. Another one has 300.000 assigned - where the index_only scan loops 1.000.000 times and takes 40 seconds total. Is this the effect of the "order" of records you identified as problem?